# Клонирование map обьекта

Tags: java

Как с помощью java клонировать `Map<Integer , ArrayList<String>> = new LinkedHashMap<>()` полностью, с ключами.

С примером клонирования.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уточни, что ты имеешь ввиду под клонированием. Сделать другой Map, содержащий те же ссылки на ключи и значения можно при помощи метода [putAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29). Плюс, в каждой реализации, есть конструктор, принимающий в качестве аргумента объект класса Map, [пример для LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap%28java.util.Map%29). Собственно пример кода:

```
Map<String,String> srcMap = new HashMap<>();//исходный Map
srcMap.put("key1","val1");
srcMap.put("key2","val2");
Map<String,String> destMap = new HashMap<>(srcMap);//через конструктор
Map<String,String> destMap2 = new HashMap<>();
destMap2.putAll(srcMap);//через putAll
```

Если же ты хочешь клонировать Map, при этом сделав копии объектов ключей и значений, то для каждого шаблона должна быть отдельная реализации. Для твоего случая:

```
public  LinkedHashMap<Integer , ArrayList<String>> cloneMap( LinkedHashMap<Integer , ArrayList<String>> srcMap)
    {
        LinkedHashMap<Integer , ArrayList<String>> destMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Set<Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>>> set = srcMap.entrySet();
        for(Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry:set)
        {
            destMap.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue()));
        }
        return destMap;

    }
```

Обрати внимания, что я не делаю копии объектов типа **Integer** и **String**, т.к. они неизменяемы. Плюс к тому, я использую конкретные реализации в объявлениях, но только ради сходства один в один с твоим вопросом.